# BLDC motor: multiplexing in order to control more motors?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

Is it possible to use a multiplexer in order to save some money ? The goal is to control up to 8 BLDC motors. I thought of a brakeout board based on the [L6234 driver](http://www.timzaman.com/2015/04/l6234-brushless-motor-controller-breakout/). I would like to run only one motor at a time. The motors are [nanotec BLDC](http://us.nanotec.com/products/1544-df45-flat-brushless-dc-motor/) motors 24V 50W.

Comment: Are you trying to multiplex a few control signals into many drivers or multiplex one driver into many motors? The first could be reasonable, the latter not so much.

Comment: A typical multiplexer is going to melt if you put 50W(!) through it. You could buy a relay-based switching circuit though.

Comment: If you disconnect the motor while in operation you will burn the driver, so perhaps is cheaper to make a batch of your own PCB, rather to spend money for switches, relays, etc..

Answer (score 1):

To multiplex bldc you need a brake, so once you leave it uncontrolled, it will not move. Other than that, it very much depends on application.